# Operations triggered by .on("request") event in Playwright Python sync do not finish before tests proceed

Tags: playwright-python

I am writing automated tests for a web app using Playwright and Python (Pytest), and am trying to implement checks for validity of queries sent to API.

Currently I am setting up a listener for "request" event and triggering a handler on requests I want to check.

The handler extracts statements from request headers using regex patterns and verifies if the request contains correct statements (expected statements are defined earlier, before the handler is triggered even).

The problem I am encountering is that before the handler can finish all operations the main body of the test proceeds, failing subsequent checks as a result.

Patterns are for extracting from ODATA filter string.

Code snippet of the code handler triggers, part of a class hence init:

```
def __init__():
    self.filter_extract_pattern = re.compile("\\$filter=.*&")
    self.statements_extract_pattern = re.compile("\\([^()]*\\)")

def _extract_filter_from_request(self, request: Request) -> str:
    catalog_filter = self.filter_extract_pattern.findall(request.header_value(":path"))[0]
    return unquote(catalog_filter)

def verify_request(self, request: Request) -> None:
    filter_string = self._extract_filter_from_request(request)

    statements_in_request = self.statements_extract_pattern.findall(filter_string)
    ...
    ...
```

The test function and handler function, non-relevant fixtures and steps skipped:

```
def on_request(request: Request):
    if some_criteria:
        verify_request(request) # part of a class in actual code

def test_something(pom_fixture):
    pom_fixture.page.on("request", on_request)

    some_element.click() # triggers the request

    some_checks
```

EDIT: For clarification, I have to verify multiple requests triggered by one action in the app.

What I found using debugger is that program leaves the handler on the line where `statements_in_request` is defined (pattern.findall()), before finishing the rest of operations.

---

- I found that adding some kind of page.wait_for_timeout() statement after triggering the request, but before the checks causes handler to pick up the work and finish before the checks. The wait can't be too short, i.e. 2 seconds worked only some times, but 3 seconds worked almost always. I don't want to do this solution, because it adds unnecessary wait to the tests.
- I tried to use `threading` Python library, but (probably due to how Playwright Python is implemented) it did not work. If I used events, and tried to `event.wait()` before the checks program stopped doing anything and did not go back to the handler. Starting a separate thread did not work either.

What I would expect to happen is for Playwright to not proceed with the main test before all the functions triggered by .on("request") events are finished.

It's likely that I could achieve this using Playwright async api, but I have never used it and don't want to commit to that method without being certain it would work since it would take quite some time to rewrite existing codebase. At the same time I feel like this should be the default behavior for sync api.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: I faced with same problem. Haven't you found any solutions to handle multiple requests?

Comment: I was able to solve this, but frankly don't fully remember how and can't check (switched jobs). Sorry for leaving the question hanging.

The only thing I'm sure of - the solution wasn't far removed from what I had in the question. In my particular use case I had a handler in a class, let's call it RequestChecker, and that class also stored what statements I was expecting in those requests and had a method I used for an assertion at the end of the test. So all operations on requests and later checks were performed by that singular object of RequestChecker class if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [expect_request](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-request):

```
with pom_fixture.page.expect_request(lambda request: request.url == "http://example.com") as second:
    some_element.click()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work in some cases, since sometimes multiple requests can be sent at once (triggered by one action) and I need to verify each one.

I've updated the question to clarify that.